# Почему date_parser не работает как ожидается (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

Мой csv содержит даты. Именно даты, без времени. И, когда я читаю данные, я бы хотел, чтобы в колонках с датами был `datetime.date`, а не `Timestamp`. У меня вопрос почему не работает подход ниже:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


def date_parser(dates):
    return pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y-%m-%d', exact=True, errors='coerce').date()


data = """date;num
2022-10-10;1
2022-10-23;2
2022-10-23;3"""

dff = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), date_parser=date_parser, parse_dates=['date'], delimiter=';')
```

Колонка `date` все равно содержит `Timestamp`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755146/why-does-pandas-return-timestamps-instead-of-datetime-objects-when-calling-pd-to

Answer (score 3):

Timestamp - это внутренний формат хранения даты, вне зависимости от того, просто ли это дата, или дата со временем (технически - любая дата включает в себя время). datetime.date - это скорее способ отображения. поэтому можете сделать так:

```
def date_parser(dates):
    return pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y-%m-%d', exact=True, errors='coerce')
# здесь убрать метод-модификатор date()
```

а здесь - добавить:

```
dff["date"][0].date()
```

> datetime.date(2022, 10, 10)